What is this material on a concrete slab?
I am in the process of replacing some damaged LVP with more LVP and I am noticing a material present on the concrete slab that I can't identify. It looks like yellowed paper. The house was built in the late 80s so I am concerned if this could be asbestos. Does anyone know what this is?


https://imgur.com/a/CLE39on

The swirls look like old tile cement.

Looks like the fiber tile-backing material, stuck to the old glue. It might have asbestos, as I believe EPA did not successfully ban asbestos in floor tiles until 1989. Get it tested if you're concerned, or take appropriate precautions (exclude others, PPE, wet work methods, proper disposal) and remove it if you are permitted to in your locale.

It is not asbestos.
It is the old trowel grade adhesive used for the prior flooring that was laid previously.
Asbestos was outlawed in the late 70's. If it was black, it would be more of a concern, for that was the color of the adhesive used when old floor tile did contain asbestos.
